# How to remove two lowest file (by their name) from directory

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I have a directory with the following files name:

```
01.02.2010.txt
02.02.2010.txt
03.02.2010.txt
04.02.2010.txt
```

I have read the name of files without their extension:

```
fs.readdir('./files', function (err, items) {
    items.forEach(function (file) {
        console.log(file.slice(0,-5))
    });
});
```

what i want is to remove two last files which has a lowest date from directory.

do you have an idea how to do this with `node.js`, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generate date for each file in the list `files` variables based on te name of the file which already contain the date. After having dates in `dates` variables I sort all the dates because list of files can be in the wrong order. After  sorting dates I retrieve only the first two elements in the arrays of date and generates files names based on dates and stores files name in `filesNames` varible.

```js
var files =["04.02.2010.txt","01.02.2010.txt","03.02.2010.txt", "02.02.2010.txt"];

// Loop through the list of file and generate date corresponding to the name of each file
var dates = []
files.forEach(function(date){
 var matches = date.match(/^(.+)\.txt$/);
 var dateTxt = matches[1].split('.');
 var fileDate = new Date(dateTxt[2], dateTxt[1], dateTxt[0]);
 dates.push(fileDate);
});

// Sort list of dates
dates.sort(function (date1, date2) {
 return date1 - date2
});

// Get the 2 lowest dates
var datesToDeletes = dates.slice(0,2);

// Regenerates filesnames
var filesNames = []
datesToDeletes.forEach(function(d){
 var date = d.getDate()
 // Add 0 before date if the month has only one number 
 date = (String(date).length == 1)? "0" + date : date;
 var month = d.getMonth()
 // Add 0 before month if the month has only one number 
 month = (String(month).length == 1)? "0" + month : month;
 var year = d.getFullYear();
 var dateString = date + '.' + month + '.' + year;
 var fileName = dateString + '.txt';
 filesNames.push(fileName);
})

// Deletes files
filesNames.forEach(function(file){
 var path = "" + file;

    // I put console log just for debugging purpose
 console.log(path)

 // Delete each file
    // Here you can delete the file because you have the name of the file in the path variable
 /*
  fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
    throw err;
  });
 */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly just a bit of thinking.

You have the format `mm.dd.yyyy.txt`.

Now, we can write a quick function to compare two dates:

```
// Assume f1, f2 are filenames
function compareDates(f1, f2) {
    var d1 = f1.split("."),
        d2 = f2.split(".");

        var temp;
        temp = d1[2];
        d1[2] = d1[1];
        d1[1] = temp;

        temp = d2[2];
        d2[2] = d2[1];
        d2[1] = temp;

    for (var i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (parseInt(d1[i]) < parseInt(d2[i]))
            return f1;
        else if (parseInt(d1[i]) > parseInt(d2[i]))
            return f2;
    }

    return f1;
}
```

That function will take two filenames as inputs and output the filename with the earlier date. Once you have that function you can just loop through your list like this:

```
var earliest = [items[0], items[1]];
var index = 0;

if (compareDates(items[0], items[1]) == items[1])
    index++;

items.forEach(function(file) {
    if (compareDates(earliest[index], file) == file) {
        earliest[index] = file;
        if (compareDates(earliest[index], earliest[!index]) == earliest[!index])
            index = !index;
    }
});
```

At this point, the array `earliest` will contain the two filenames with the earliest dates.  Hope this helped!

EDIT: As another said, you can delete the actual file like this:

```
fs.unlink(filename, function(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    console.log(`${filename} deleted.`);
});
```